# Web view Scrolling issue when add hardwareAccelerated is false

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-layout, android-webview

I made a web view application in which I show a web site. there is a side navigation bar on web site. When I put hardwareAccelerated=false in manifest then that navigation displays without any problem. When I give value true then that navigation bar displays at a slow speed. 
My problem is solved when I give value false in manifest to hardwareAccelerated but because of this web view scrolling behaves incorrectly. It gets stuck on some points(jitters) and scrolls back automatically.
What is the possible reason for this behavior?

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView=findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    ///CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie("https://helpers.ie/dashboard", "ci_session=ih5amh1qp52puqnqhv8a55iqnh005mqg");
    webView.loadUrl("https://helpers.ie/dashboard");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

        }
        @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
            // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
            onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView is noted to have problems with hardware acceleration. According to the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel), you're enabling and disabling hardware acceleration at the app level. have you tried disabling it only for that particular webview?
this would be done as

```
webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

what are the results of View.isHardwareAccelerated()? how is the website made? is it static html/css or is it using some sort of js framework?, for eg jquery has issues with hardware acceleration

in comments you've pointed out thi problem doesn't occur on chrome so you can check out[chrome custom tab](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs#whentouse). this can be styled and controlled in your app

```
String url = ¨https://paul.kinlan.me/¨;
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

Comment: my web site had a side bar menu

Comment: which shows slowly when I enable but then scrolling is ok but when I disable the hardware accelerated then side menu shows ok smoothly but then scrolling makes problems

Comment: have you tried putting another website with a sidebar in your webview and seeing if it has the same issues?

Comment: no but that web site is working great on iOS app. I also made the iOS app of that web site

Comment: yes but android and iOS are fundamentally different in hardware and software stacks. please try another website and see whether the issue is because you're using some esoteric js. iOS is more optimized for js than android in general

Comment: for web app it is ok but for one only it makes problem

Comment: please post some code of what you've done and also a link to your website

Comment: your website uses lots of js(and jquery) which has issues with hardware acceleration on android. i hope someone else can answer your question

Comment: so I need to add tag of js and query also in my question??

Comment: this web site is ok on chrome web browser on android

Comment: in that case use https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs#whentouse chrome custom tab